# How to breakline inside logical OR Regex operation

Tags: r, regex, line-breaks

The Goal is find out multi strings by with **Breakline** Logical OR Regex

**Example**

```
GG <- c("aa","bb")
```

**Normal Expression**

```
grepl("aa"|"bb",GG)

[1]  TRUE TRUE # --- It is what i want
```

**Breakline Expression**

```
grepl("aa"|
      "bb",GG)

[1]  TRUE FALSE # --- Not able the find all the result
```

How to **BREAKLINE** when the multi conditions are **long strings** ?

(Actuall strings is like :

```
"Health Attention Senior Department Session One |
Product Development Division Number Six|
Management and Risk Controller Department Number Seven"
```

) Too long to contain them all in one line scripts

Comment: The whole pattern has to be quoted as a single string, e.g. `grepl("aa|bb", c("aa", "bb"))`. The usual way to combine multiple clauses with `|` is therefore with `paste` with `sep = "|"`. If they're exact matches like this, you could just use `%in%` instead of regex, though.

Comment: @alistaire you probably meant using `paste` with `collapse = "|"` instead of `sep = "|"`.. right??

Comment: @Mankind_008 Depends if you're calling it on a predefined vector

Comment: Thankyou alistaire. It is the following script match what your answer ? grepl(paste("aa|bb",collapse = " | "),GG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `(?x)` I think the below would work:

```
grepl("(?x)aa|
        bb",GG, perl=TRUE)
```

Outputs:

```
#> grepl("(?x)aa|
#+         bb",GG, perl=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

**From documentation:**

> (?s) (single line, so a dot matches all characters, even new lines:
>   equivalent to Perl's /s) and (?x) (extended, whitespace data
>   characters are ignored unless escaped and comments are allowed:
>   equivalent to Perl's /x)

You can read entire text [here](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/regex.html)

Comment: cool use of an obscure operator

Comment: Thankyou PKumar, awesome apporach that teach a lot as i am newbies of programming

Comment: PKumar, That is strange after i test for the long sentences , your method doesn't work , Are there any part i missed  ?    HH <- c("Health Attention Senior Department Session One",
"Product Development Division Number Six")  ; grepl("(?x)Health Attention Senior Department Session One|
Product Development Division Number Six",HH,perl = TRUE)  #[1] FALSE,FALSE

Comment: @rane, I think you are doing it in wrong way.What do you want to achieve, first part in grepl is regex the second part is string in which you want to find match. You cant find that big string in HH unless it contains any if those strings. Print the value of HH here . I have to see what HH contains

Comment: Actually , i wanna find match with multi conditions which is a middle long strings with whitespace .  If you copy the following script : HH <- c("Health Attention Senior Department Session One","Product Development Division Number Six")
grepl("(?x)Health Attention Senior Department Session One|Product Development Division Number Six",HH,perl = TRUE)   . and test , result : [1] FALSE FALSE     .  What is making (?x) become not functioning ?

Comment: Thankyou PKumar , The following method solved the problems .  grepl(paste0("Health Attention Senior Department Session One|",
             "Product Development Division Number Six"),HH,perl = TRUE)

Comment: @rane, you can try this as well, its a hack but works : `grepl(file.path("Health Attention Senior Department Session One",
                "Product Development Division Number Six",fsep="|"), HH) 
` by the way in cases like this you should try to use `%in%` , grep command is mostly used in cases where we have a pattern to match, In this case its a direct match (Use %in% in these cases)